# z3 datatype matching without a quantifier

Tags: z3

Say I make a datatype `A` in z3:

```
(declare-datatypes () ((A (b (bx Int)) (c (cx Int)))))
```

Now, I can declare a variable `t`, and then, say, assert that `t` is a `c` type:

```
(declare-fun t () A)
(assert (exists ((x Int)) (= t (c x))))
```

However, this requires an existential quantifier. My question is: is it possible to do this *without* a quantifier?

Specifically, I'd like an expression, like `is_c t` or something, which is equivalent to `(exists ((x Int)) (= t (c x)))`.

I had expected this to be straightforward, since in most functional programming languages with sum types, there's an elimination form for them, usually pattern matching, like `match t of b x => false; c x => true`. But I haven't been able to find anything of this nature in the z3 documentation. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You automatically get a tester, as an indexed identifier: `(_ is c)` for each constructor `c`.

See Section 4.2.3 of http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2017-07-18.pdf. The relevant part is on page 61 (the second paragraph):

> On successfully executing this command, for each constructor c in a
>   declared datatype δ, the solver will also automatically declare a
>   tester with rank δ Bool. The tester’s name is an indexed identifier
>   (see Section 3.3) of the form (_ is c).

Comment: Thanks! BTW, it looks like this doesn't work until z3 4.6. (Also, I thought the syntax was `(t is c)`, but it's actually `((_ is c) t)`. Heh.)

Comment: Z3 4.6 implements the SMT2.6 syntax for data-types. Before that it would rely on custom identifiers, automatically generated, named after the constructor but prefixed with an "is-" or "is_". Given that the syntax is now described in the document for SMT2.6 it makes sense to simply follow the conventions used there.